# How does the stack unwind if at the end of a recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

After the code below compiles and the recursion base case is met - how does the computer deal with the stack? Does it return `None` all the way up until the initial call and then exit?

```
arr = []
count = 0

def recur(count, x):
    if count == x:
       arr.append(x)

    else:
       recur(count+1, x)

recur(0, 5)
```

Comment: It returns whatever each function returns. Since here you have no explicit `return` statement, then yes it returns None by default, but this isn't specific to recursion.

Comment: Thanks - So quick follow up, does traversing back up the stack with None's take a significant amount of time if the stack is large?